# How to translate Dutch to English in Python using dictionary

Tags: python, machine-translation

I am trying to translate I am Jason using this code, but when I use it, it prints out nothing, unless I do one word like hello, then it prints out guten tag, but that's it. Plus, I can't turn the input data into lowercase to be able to compare it to the dictionary. What can I do to make this code work?

```
name = input("Please enter your name\n")
data = [input("Please enter sentence\n")]
data = data.lower() #to make sentence lowercase to be able to compare it to the words in the dictionary
dictionary = {"hello": "hallo", "i" : "ik", "am" : "ben"}

dictionary[name] = name
for word in data:
    if word in dictionary:
        print (dictionary[word],)
```

This is the traceback

*Please enter your name

Jason

Please enter sentence

I am Jason*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users...", line 3, in <module>
    data = data.lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Does your code produce an Exception? When asking about code that produces an Exception always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it as text then format it as code.

Comment: I included the traceback in my edit

Comment: `data = [d.lower() for d in data]`

Comment: Thank you, that removed the traceback, but it still doesn't output a sentence or anything at all and just ends the program when I write more than two words, even if they're included in the dictionary

Comment: Python tells you what is wrong: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` at line 3. So, `data` has no function lower() you can apply it to ! Because `data`is of type `[]`, not `str`.

Comment: I would suggest you trying to think about what you want your code to do and to understand step by step what is actually doing. For now, what your code does is: to put a entire sentence inside a list (without tokenizing it), then you tried to apply a function intended for strings in this one-sized list. And, after setting the corresponding dict correctly you iterate over your one-sized list. Therefore, you only get successful cases when your entire sentence is composed of only one word.

Answer (score 0):

You made a list out of the user's response

```
In [26]: data = [input("Please enter sentence\n")]

Please enter sentence
You are Jason

In [27]: data
Out[27]: ['You are Jason']
```

lists don't have a `lower` method.
First get the user's response and turn it into lower case.

```
In [28]: data = input("Please enter sentence\n")

Please enter sentence
You are Jason

In [29]: data
Out[29]: 'You are Jason'

In [30]: data = data.lower()

In [31]: data
Out[31]: 'you are jason'
```

Then [split the string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on whitespace to get a list of individual words.

```
In [32]: data = data.split()

In [33]: data
Out[33]: ['you', 'are', 'jason']
```

Comment: I tried the data.split() and it says                                                                                  
data = data.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'